# How to add a custom button on change_form template django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to get the add a custom button with the history in `change_form`. I got the button like this:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% block object-tools-items %}

    {{ block.super }}

    <li>
        <a href="export/" class="addlink">Publish</a>
    </li>

{% endblock %}
```

What I want is, if the published field is True, show `Unpublish` in the button instead of `Publish`.

`{{ adminform.fields.published }}` is giving me nothing. How can I access the value. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`{{ adminform.form.instance.published }}`